# Issues with my main.css file in a Tailwind and Vuejs Project

Tags: webpack, vue.js, frameworks, vue-cli, tailwind-css

Trying to set up a Vuejs project using webpack that includes TailwindCSS. I've been following the instructions from Jerrie's blog post (https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-tailwindcss-with-vuejs/) as well as Adam's example on github (https://github.com/adamwathan/vue-cli-tailwind-example). but I keep running into an issue when it comes to building my main.css file.

My Steps:

1.) Create A Vue Project -

```
vue init webpack tailwind-test
```

2.) Then I run NPM install -

```
npm install
```

With my Vue Project set up I've been trying to add Tailwind with some difficulty.

3.) Install Tailwind NPM -

```
npm install tailwindcss --save-dev
```

4.) Then add my config file -

```
./node_modules/.bin/tailwind init tailwind.js
```

This is where I'm having issues...

5.) Create a CSS file -

```
cd src 
cd assets
mkdir styles 
touch main.css
```

6.) Then I enter my main.css file and add -

```
@tailwind preflight; 
@tailwind utilities;
```

From here my text editor is returning the error "at-rule unknown" which is preventing me from updating putting the finishing touches to my .postcssrc.js file.

Any feedback would be really appreciated!

Thanks 
-MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you including `main.css` into your project?

Also, since the vue webpack template uses PostCSS you should likely do like the docs suggest.

```
@import "tailwindcss/preflight";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Though `@tailwind` should still work.

Comment: Hi Bill, not sure how I missed that but it's seemed to have solved my main.css issue! Thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score -1):

My recommendation is to install postCSS language support and rename .css to .pcss then change the references in your package.json scripts (or whatever build scripts you are using for tailwind) from .css to.pcss and everything should work fine.

@apply rule is also compatible with postCSS: https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/issues/325